# gradle 4.9 - gradlew and java 10 still get: Could not determine java version from '10'

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

gradlew seems to still have problems with java 10 (please see below).

i remove gradlew/, do a gradle wrapper with 4.9, and try a gradlew -v, i get some warnings and: Could not determine java version from '10'.

does anyone have a workaround?

edit: the gradle-wrapper properties says:

```
D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit\gradle\wrapper>cat gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

but i *just* created that with 4.9, so i am confused :(

edit2: @Aris suggested looking at the build file and sure enough, i have a "task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.14' }" in there.

edit3: removing the wrapper task from the build file and creating another by doing a gradle wrapper works fine!

java version reports:

```
D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>java --version
java 10 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>




D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>gradle -v

Welcome to Gradle 4.9!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Experimental APIs for creating and configuring tasks lazily
 - Pass arguments to JavaExec via CLI
 - Auxiliary publication dependency support for multi-project builds
 - Improved dependency insight report

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/release-notes.html

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
 (file:/D:/dev/gradle-4.9/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar) to method java.lang.Object.
finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groov
y.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflect
ive access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-07-16 08:14:03 UTC
Revision:     efcf8c1cf533b03c70f394f270f46a174c738efc

Kotlin DSL:   0.18.4
Kotlin:       1.2.41
Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          10 ("Oracle Corporation" 10+46)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>ls -F
165705.JPG*              getalllogfiles.bat*     loggger.dtd*
IMG_2708.jpg*            getlogfiles.bat*        pull.bat*
bin/                     gradle/                 run.bat*
build/                   gradlew*                runlogserver.bat*
build.gradle*            gradlew.bat*            save/
chainsaw.bat*            here.sh*                settings.gradle*
chainsawconfig.xml*      histories.WinMerge*     src/
controller.bat*          jlogviewer_1_0_0d.jar*  t1.bat*
deleteemptylogfiles.sh*  junk.bat*               testpb.bat*
deletelogfiles.bat*      lib/                    tmp.jar*
eyedocs.jpg*             listalllogfiles.bat*
filterLogs.sh*           log/

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>rm -r gradle/

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>gradle wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:comman
d_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 30s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>gradlew -v

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

D:\ray\dev\conradapps\rabbit>
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle wrapper properties please?

Comment: Also what version wrapper is your project using?

Comment: please see edit.

Comment: I don't see the gradle properties are you sure you edited the original question?

Comment: should be there now.

Comment: so why is 4.9 putting in the 2.14?

Comment: Can you also post the `build.gradle` of the project?

Comment: @ Aris good idea, i have a: "task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.14' }" in there. post an answer and i will check it.

Comment: removing that line does not help,. will try making a new wrapper.

Comment: Don't remove ti just edit the task to use a newer distribution and try again.

Comment: sorry, already removed. now there is a 4.9 in there and gradlew -v is happy :)

Comment: Nice. I hope you understood the root of the problem.

Comment: Would you like me to make this over to an answer to upvote etc etc?

Comment: yes, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you upgraded your local Gradle distribution to a new version, the one used by your gradle wrapper was still very old, meaning it was not supporting new Java versions. This is evident by your `gradlew.properties` file and the `build.gradle` wrapper task's version.

Fixing the gradle wrapper task's gradle version should fix this. You should then be able to re-run the wrapper task and create a correct wrapper.